# How to get rid of the mirroring effect in edit mode after applying the mirror modifier in Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I can't figure out how to get rid of the mirroring effect of the mirror modifier even after I have applied it. I am working in Blender 2.8 but still can't figure out how to get rid of this mirroring effect. As you can see in the picture below I don't have the mirror modifier on the mesh anymore since I have applied it but yet the mesh is still mirorring. If anyone has an answer please let me know.o[image]

Comment: Can you see if there is an X-mirror function turned on? It was a Mesh Option in Blender 2.79 - don't know where it is in 2.8.

Comment: I found where that is in 2.8. It's under the picture with a screwdriver and a wrench called active tool and workspace settings. Its under mesh options.

Comment: OK.  Was it enabled?

Comment: Why would you have 2 solidify modifiers there?.. That's a mess...

Answer (score -1):

Check left toolbar, options tab: Mesh options, X mirror.